# Correctly doing redirect_to :back in Ruby on Rails when referrer is not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I'm having a problem with `redirect_to :back`. Yes, it's referrers.

I often get the exception

> (ActionController::RedirectBackError) "No HTTP_REFERER was set in the request to this action, so redirect_to :back could not be called successfully. If this is a test, make sure to specify request.env[\"HTTP_REFERER\"]."

I realize that this is a result of a referrer not being available. Is there a way that, for example, one can set a session variable on each access with the last page visited, and, when HTTP_REFERER is not available, utilize this session variable to redirect to?

Comment: I have the same error in an update action, which is strange because referrer couldn't be empty (as request would be from a form), but some user just managed to do this which I don't know how.

Answer (score 153):

It is unlikely that you *do* have a session and *don't* have a referrer.

The situation that a referrer is not set isn't that uncommon and I usually rescue that expection:

```
def some_method
  redirect_to :back
rescue ActionController::RedirectBackError
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

If you do this often (which I think is a bad idea) you can wrap it in an other method like Maran suggests.

BTW I think that's a bad idea because this makes the userflow ambiguous. Only in the case of a login this is sensible.

**UPDATE**: As several people pointed out this [no longer works](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22506) with Rails 5.
Instead, use `redirect_back`, this method also supports a fallback. The code then becomes:

```
def some_method
  redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
end
```

Comment: I suspect that I would alter this to use rescue_from instead.

Comment: @BobAman IMO we could use `rescue_from` if the controller had multiple `redirect_to :back`

Comment: don't works with rails 5, ActionController::RedirectBackError is undefined... what solution?

Comment: Use this instead: `redirect_to (request.referrer || root_url)`

Answer (score 39):

Here's my little redirect_to_back method:

```
  def redirect_to_back(default = root_url)
    if request.env["HTTP_REFERER"].present? and request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] != request.env["REQUEST_URI"]
      redirect_to :back
    else
      redirect_to default
    end
  end
```

You can pass an optional url to go somewhere else if http_refferrer is blank.

Answer (score 38):

```
def store_location
  session[:return_to] = request.request_uri
end

def redirect_back_or_default(default)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  session[:return_to] = nil
end
```

Try that! (Thanks to the [Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/tree/master) plugin)

Comment: This is a good solution, but I'd urge anyone using it to keep in mind that it can "break" in a manner extremely confusing to the user if he or she is using multiple tabs to browse your app.

Comment: +1 For answering the question and not criticizing design methods.

Answer (score 34):

**Core feature**

`redirect_back` is a core feature from Rails 5+, it is available in the `ActionController::Redirecting` module that is already included in`ApplicationController::Base`.

> DEPRECATION WARNING: `redirect_to :back` is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 5.1. Please use `redirect_back(fallback_location: fallback_location)` where `fallback_location` represents the location to use if the request has no HTTP referer information.

EDIT : [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.beta2/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb#L108)

Comment: Link to source, please

Comment: @Chrisbloom7 This is a warning message I had while running Rails 5.0.0beta3 with `redirect_to :back`.

Answer (score 21):

Maybe it's late but I would like to share my method which also preserve options:

```
  def redirect_back_or_default(default = root_path, *options)
    tag_options = {}
    options.first.each { |k,v| tag_options[k] = v } unless options.empty?
    redirect_to (request.referer.present? ? :back : default), tag_options
  end
```

You can use it like:

```
redirect_back_or_default(some_path, :notice => 'Hello from redirect', :status => 301)
```

Answer (score 15):

updated: Rails 5 added redirect_back method (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22506/), better just use:

```rb
redirect_back fallback_location: answer_path(answer), flash: { error: I18n.t('m.errors')}
```

For rails lower than 5.0 can still use the old way below:

similar to @troex's answer, add this to your application controller

```
def redirect_back_or_default(default = root_path, options = {})
  redirect_to (request.referer.present? ? :back : default), options
end
```

then use it in your controller

```
redirect_back_or_default answer_path(answer), flash: { error: I18n.t('m.errors')}
```

Answer (score 12):

### redirect_back_or_to (Rails 7+)

Rails 7 presents a new idiomatic way to redirect back or to the fallback location.

Quoting directly from the official Rails API docs:

```rb
redirect_back_or_to(fallback_location, allow_other_host: true, **args)
```

> Redirects the browser to the page that issued the request (the referrer) if possible, otherwise redirects to the provided default fallback location.

> The referrer information is pulled from the HTTP Referer (sic) header on the request. This is an optional header and its presence on the request is subject to browser security settings and user preferences. If the request is missing this header, the fallback_location will be used.

```rb
redirect_back_or_to({ action: "show", id: 5 })
redirect_back_or_to @post
redirect_back_or_to "http://www.rubyonrails.org"
redirect_back_or_to "/images/screenshot.jpg"
redirect_back_or_to posts_url
redirect_back_or_to proc { edit_post_url(@post) }
redirect_back_or_to '/', allow_other_host: false
```

It is also worth mentioning that 
the Rails 5 way `redirect_back(fallback_location: '/things/stuff')` 
has exactly the same behavior as newly introduced `redirect_back_or_to('/things/stuff')`.

**Sources:**

- [Pull Request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40671).
- `redirect_back_or_to` [official docs](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_back_or_to).
- `redirect_back` [official docs](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_back).

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I encountered the same issue where either I had to redirect `:back` or to specific page. After going to a lot of solution, I finally found this which is simple and seems to solve the issue:

```
if request.env["HTTP_REFERER"].present?
    redirect_to :back
else
    redirect_to 'specific/page'
end
```

If you want to use `session` details, do it in the else part of the code.