# Rails - how can I capture the URL that directed to the current action in my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, routes, redirect

I need to see what page a request came from in my controller so I could be able to redirect back to it. For example, if I'm on a page showing a specific product (say `/products/1`) and it has a link to its vendor (`/vendors/12`), I want to be able to detect inside the vendors_controller that I came to that page from `/products/1`. Is there a simple way in Rails to achieve this, so that I could access it via params or session? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`redirect_to :back` can be used within a controller to redirect back to the page that issued the request. It uses the value of the `HTTP_REFERER` header to determine where to go back to.

Comment: I didn't know you could do this - fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
redirect_to request.referrer
```

as documented here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/AbstractRequest.html

To be honest I think this is what the back thing does above. Also see this elsewhere on S/O

[Correctly doing redirect_to :back in Ruby on Rails when referrer is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771656/correctly-doing-redirect-to-back-in-ruby-on-rails-when-referrer-is-not-available)