# Preserving referrer on redirect_to in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For webtracking purposes, I'd like to preserve the HTTP referrer when using `redirect_to` in Rails. This is needed to redirect to the respective language version.

Code example:

```
redirect_to "/#{Option[:locales].first}", :status => 301
```

How can I preserve the referrer without using query parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a handful of ways detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771656/correctly-doing-redirect-to-back-in-ruby-on-rails-when-referrer-is-not-availabl).

My preferred way to do it is set a before_filter for `store_referrer` in your controller that calls a method like this in my `application_controller`. Then use the `redirect_back_or_default` method in your actions to handle the re-direct.

```
def store_referrer
  session[:return_to] = request.request_uri
end

def redirect_back_or_default(default)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  session[:return_to] = nil
end
```

You can also look at the `redirect_to :back` method that is available in Rails, or if you're using Authlogic/Devise, they both come with similar helpers to do the same thing.

Take a look through the linked thread, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12064410/403664) suggestion by [troex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216254/troex) is a good one.