# Submit same form from different pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I develop a new project using **Rails 4**.
In this project there is a sign-up form which should be located in different places.

Regardless of its location, the form action goes to the same controller and action. If everything is ok, user is redirected to its account settings page. Otherwise errors would appear in the same location user tried to sign-up.

I wonder what would be the best practice to implement what I want. I don't want to use ajax, just use the built-in mechanism of Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Your sign-up form should be a partial (i.e. signup/_form.html.erb).  You can then render this in any other view:

If views are in same location:
    `<%= render partial: 'form' %>`

If views are in other locations:
    `<%= render partial: 'other_location/form' %>`

Comment: The problem is how to handle the postback with errors to different pages. Two aspects I can think of: (1) redirecting to different pages according to the place the form was rendered and (2) create the necessary variables for each action

Comment: The simplest approach would just be to redirect back to the requesting page (as eluded to) and include a flash error for display.  Here's a post that outlines this + some other use cases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771656/correctly-doing-redirect-to-back-in-ruby-on-rails-when-referrer-is-not-availabl

Answer (score 0):

create a partial _form.html.erb under the authentication folder for example, then you can render this partial in any other view: `<%= render partial: 'form' %> or <%= render partial: 'other_folder/form' %>`

Comment: This is quite obvious. The problem is how to handle the postback.