# Redirect after sign in with Devise 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I know there are a ton of questions like this, and a few wiki articles, but nothing seems to work.

They all seem to end up in some sort of redirect loop or something else like that.

This is the last thing I did, based on [these instructions](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    sign_in_url = new_user_session_url
    if request.referer == sign_in_url
      super
    else
      stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Yet this is what my logs shows happens when I sign in:

```
Started POST "/users/login" for ::1 at 2016-06-15 16:19:57 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"iGvdqYUdMgS/XXqTrh+XpW3PWQn473q/lm/lqsBeRcrcP+JRg==", "user"=>{"email"=>"abc@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
  User Load (4.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "abc@test.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (8.2ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = $1, "last_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = $5  [["current_sign_in_at", 2016-06-15 21:19:57 UTC], ["last_sign_in_at", 2016-06-15 05:59:17 UTC], ["sign_in_count", 10], ["updated_at", 2016-06-15 21:19:57 UTC], ["id", 1546]]
   (2.6ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login
Completed 302 Found in 218ms (ActiveRecord: 15.6ms)


Started GET "/login" for ::1 at 2016-06-15 16:19:57 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  User Load (3.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1546], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)


Started GET "/login" for ::1 at 2016-06-15 16:19:57 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  User Load (2.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1546], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)


Started GET "/login" for ::1 at 2016-06-15 16:19:57 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1546], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)


Started GET "/login" for ::1 at 2016-06-15 16:19:57 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  User Load (3.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1546], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

How do I redirect to the page the user is coming from after they have logged in (or registered) without getting this loop?

**Edit 1**

Based on the feedback from SsoulLess, this is what happens.

For starters, the infinite loop no longer happens - so that's good. However, it doesn't actually redirect to the right place.

When I add a `binding.pry` right into that `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` method and explore my `session` hash, this is what I see:

```
[1] pry(#<Devise::SessionsController>)> session[:referer]
=> nil
[2] pry(#<Devise::SessionsController>)> session[:referrer]
=> nil
```

In theory, it should have a value, because of what I did. I was coming from a `Question#Show` view. Nothing to do with `Users`.

What else should store the previous path I am coming from before login?

**Edit 2**

Based on further suggestions from SsoulLess, this is what my code looks like now:

```
ApplicationController.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  #aplication_controller.rb
  def authenticate_user!(resource=nil)
    session[:referer] = request.fullpath
    redirect_to(new_user_registration_path, success: 'create an account or log in.') unless user_signed_in?
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    #Redirect back the user to the last action he wanted to do
    if session[:referer] =~ /\/users/
        root_path
    elsif session[:referer].nil?
        root_path
    else
        session[:referer]
    end
  end
end
```

And this is my `QuestionsController`

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_question, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_voting_question, only: [:vote_up, :vote_down]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
..
..
end
```

This is what my log looks like when I am viewing a `Question#Show` and need to login.

```
Started POST "/users/login" for ::1 at 2016-06-18 19:12:03 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"chcksZ9AMvZKvzJec5IMqwDhA58dYlB9tQy7OSY9dqqWw==", "user"=>{"email"=>"abc@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
  User Load (3.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "abc@test.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (6.0ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = $1, "last_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = $5  [["current_sign_in_at", 2016-06-19 00:12:03 UTC], ["last_sign_in_at", 2016-06-15 21:19:57 UTC], ["sign_in_count", 11], ["updated_at", 2016-06-19 00:12:03 UTC], ["id", 1546]]
   (0.8ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 190ms (ActiveRecord: 11.1ms)


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-06-18 19:12:03 -0500
Processing by QuestionsController#index as HTML
  Rendering questions/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered shared/_main_page_heading.html.erb (0.6ms)
```

It still doesn't return the user back to the Question#show page like I expect.

**Edit 3**

After trying what @sohair-ahmad suggested, it still doesn't work.

This is what I get when I drop a `binding.pry` in that method and explore the `session` object:

```
   6: def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 => 7:   binding.pry
    8:   session["user_return_to"] || root_path
    9: end

[1] pry(#<Devise::SessionsController>)> session
=> #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x007fd8baa9c078 ...>
[2] pry(#<Devise::SessionsController>)> session["user_return_to"]
=> nil
[3] pry(#<Devise::SessionsController>)> exit
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 18434ms (ActiveRecord: 6.2ms)
```

The fundamental issue is that I can't find the attribute within `session` that stores the actual location before `/login`. If I could, then it would solve this.

**Edit 4**

Here is a Gist of my `application_controller.rb` and the log for the entire operation - https://gist.github.com/marcamillion/d7826b7289dc55bf4d33e688851bfc26

You will notice the first thing I did is I went to a Question#Show page. Then I logged out and it redirected me to `/`. Then from there, I went back to another `question#show` and then I logged in from there too. You will see the login process and then you will see the redirect to my root_path again. So it still isn't working, even after trying @SsoulLess's most recent updates.

**Edit 5**

After doing the latest suggestion from @SsoulLess, I get the functionality I would like for the most part....except when I go from /register -> /login and then I do login. It sends me back to /register and then keeps me in an infinite loop. See the logs below:

```
Started GET "/register" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-25 23:45:38 -0500
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Rendering devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (44.3ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 206ms (Views: 203.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-25 23:45:42 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (29.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 190ms (Views: 188.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started POST "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-25 23:45:48 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cZ+kP5Q+rSuz3G/Jxwe0fPRSOnqJdA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"abc@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
  User Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "abc@test.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.8ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = $1, "last_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = $5  [["current_sign_in_at", 2016-06-26 04:45:48 UTC], ["last_sign_in_at", 2016-06-26 04:45:04 UTC], ["sign_in_count", 27], ["updated_at", 2016-06-26 04:45:48 UTC], ["id", 1546]]
   (0.8ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/register
Completed 302 Found in 168ms (ActiveRecord: 5.3ms)


Started GET "/register" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-25 23:45:48 -0500
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1546], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)


Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-25 23:45:48 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1546], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

This is the latest `ApplicationController`, how do I modify it so I don't get this issue:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
after_action :store_location

  def store_location
    session[:previous_url] = request.referer
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    session[:previous_url] || root_path
  end

end
```

Comment: `after_sign_in_path_for` name suggests it should return a path not a url, did this code work in devise 3 ?

Comment: you can also remove `after_sign_in_path_for` definition and instead in your routes.rb add `:as => user_root_path` to the route you want to redirect to(provided your model's name is `User`)

Comment: @niceman I am just using the code snippet from the official Devise ReadME (linked in the question), so I assume it worked in Devise 3. In terms of your latter suggestion, I don't want it to redirect to a specific route. I just want to send the user back to the page they were on before they went to /login.

Comment: hmm I think you need to set `session[:referer]` yourself, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139996/how-to-redirect-to-previous-page-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: @niceman I believe Devise should be tracking all of this stuff. The `request.referrer` that the link you posted references is insufficient here. It always says `/login`, where the page I want to redirect to is the page right before `/login`.

Comment: hmmm I don't think your case is public enough to be handled by devise, but maybe Rails should have this built-in .
I think you didn't read the link carefullyl, you put `session[:referer]=request.referer` in the action responsible of the page before `/login` and then in the after_sign_in_path you use it

Comment: I updated my answer with the missing part where you need to set the referer. Hope it helps!

Comment: @marcamillion I already added another update let me know.

Comment: @SsouLlesS I updated the question again with more details.

Comment: @marcamillion please continue this on chat, join this chatroom: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/115051/marcamillion-bounty

Comment: There are multiple methods implemented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771656/correctly-doing-redirect-to-back-in-ruby-on-rails-when-referrer-is-not-availabl

Comment: Also, I have not checked the rails source code but it might be worth trying to change the variable name to something like session[:return_to] = request.fullpath to make sure rails is not overriding your variable

Comment: `Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected` sounds like you successfully logged in, then redirected to a page that is forbidding logged-in users?

Comment: @jemminger I did successfully login, but it doesn't redirect to a page that is forbidden. Here is a gist of both my `application_controller.rb` and the full log of a complete operation - https://gist.github.com/marcamillion/d7826b7289dc55bf4d33e688851bfc26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `session[:referer]` it works with the latest version of Devise.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    #Redirect back the user to the last action he wanted to do
    if session[:referer] =~ /\/users/
        root_path
    elsif session[:referer].nil?
        root_path
    else
        session[:referer]
    end
end
```

Now as you can see above, if the referer is one of the `/user/` page or the referee is nil, then we redirect to `root_path` otherwise we'll redirect to the referer, it means to the last action the user wanted to perform before log in.

### Update

Yes Im sorry, I missed the part where you set the `session[:referer]` hash, you need to set it manually when getting in the log in page:

```
#aplication_controller.rb
def authenticate_user!(resource=nil)
        session[:referer] = request.fullpath
        redirect_to( new_user_registration_path, success: 'create an account or log in.') unless user_signed_in?
    end
```

### Update 2

the `authenticate_user!` method in your application controller is overriding the `before_action :authenticate_user!` filter, this is the way you use for request login for the actions within your controllers.

So when the user wants to perform an action he needs to log in, the `before_action :authenticate_user!` filter will redirect to the log in page, but the `session[:referer]` is set in the `authenticate_user!` function in your application controller. Then you can use it in the `after_sign_in_path_for` for redirect the user to the proper action the user wanted to perform before log in.

### Update 3 - The final version that works! (almost, see below)

I understood what you want to achieve, you want to redirect the user back to the last page he visited before log in:

```
#aplication_controller.rb    
after_action :store_location

    def store_location
      # store last url as long as it isn't a /users path
      session[:previous_url] = request.referer
    end

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      session[:previous_url] || root_path
    end
```

### Update 4 (this update is added by the OP)

For the most part, Update 3 worked, but there was one edge case that sent the app into an infinite loop. If the `request.referer` was one of the Devise actions upon login. See the updated question for a complete explanation of what happens.

Here is the complete solution that handles this edge case successfully:

```
  def store_location
    # store last url as long as it isn't a /users /register /login path
    if request.referer =~ /\/users|\/login|\/register/
      session[:previous_url] = root_path
    elsif request.referer.nil?
      session[:previous_url] = root_path
    else
      session[:previous_url] = request.referer
    end
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    session[:previous_url] || root_path
  end
```

Comment: Ok this is a great start. I no longer get the infinite loop. But this doesn't quite work. Refresh the question, I have added more details about what happens when I try your solution. Thoughts?

Comment: I want to ask does devise set `session[:referer]` ? or Rails ?

Comment: I just tried your update, but I am still getting `session[:referer]` being nil.

Comment: @marcamillion it works with the `before_action :authenticate_user!` filter in your controllers. or how are you requesting log in?

Comment: I do have `before_action :authenticate_user!` in many of my controllers. But it still doesn't work with your suggestions.

Comment: I have updated the question so you can see what my latest code looks like.

Comment: After much backing and forthing in the chat, we eventually got something that works. The answer has been updated (see Update 3 for what the solution was) to include the answer that worked!

Comment: Yow, so this does work...but now I am getting a redirect loop again. I am going to update the question now.

Comment: @SsouLlesS Actually, nevermind. I got it. I also updated your answer to reflect the more complete answer that works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this [A Simpler Solution?](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update#a-simpler-solution) worked for me.

Adding snippet here

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base


  private

  # If your model is called User

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    session["user_return_to"] || root_path
  end

  # Or if you need to blacklist for some reason

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    blacklist = [new_user_session_path, new_user_registration_path] # etc...
    last_url = session["user_return_to"]
    if blacklist.include?(last_url)
      root_path
    else
     last_url
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It doesn't work though. I have updated the question to show the results of my attempt. Refresh the question to see.

Comment: This solution does not work with the@marcamillion's devise version